# Open tabs at startup in Konqueror

Tags: kubuntu, browser, kde4

When starting Chrome I can set up that it opens previously used tabs, last time when closing the browser window. 
Can I do the same in Konqueror? When I open Konqueror doesn't reopen last opened tabs, but opens a homepage.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this ? [Konqueror overview at openSuse](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/suse9.3/suselinux-userguide_en/cha.konqueror.html)

I read this statement at chap 10 point 1 from that site:

"You can save your tabs with URLs and the position of the window in a profile. This is a bit different from the session managment mentioned above. With profiles, **you have your saved tabs at hand and without intensive start-up time like with session management**."

Comment: I know about making profiles. It's not a bad solution for what I'm using it (opening lot of pdf-s in tabs), but reopening the tabs from last time would be nicer.

Comment: @enedene : ic.... sorry for the wrong answer =)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything in the documentation, but found that if a Konqueror window is open when I log off from Ubuntu then when I next launch Konqueror, it tells me that the last time it ran it crashed and offers to restore all the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can open tabs on startup with Konqueror by passing them as parameters into the konqueror commandline like this:

```
konqueror --profile filemanagement /home/myuser /home/myuser/Downloads
```

You could have figured that out yourself by typing `konqueror -help` and scrolling down to where the parameter list is defined:

```
$ konqueror -help
Usage: konqueror [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [KDE-tempfile-options] [options] [URL] 

Web browser, file manager and document viewer.

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-kde-tempfile       Show KDE-tempfile specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information           
  --                        End of options    

Options:  
  --silent                  Start without a default window, when called without URLs
  --preload                 Preload for later use. This mode does not support URLs on the command line    
  --profile <profile>       Profile to open
  --profiles                List available profiles 
  --sessions                List available sessions 
  --open-session <session>  Session to open     
  --mimetype <mimetype>     Mimetype to use for this URL (e.g. text/html or inode/directory)            
  --part <service>          Part to use (e.g. khtml or kwebkitpart)
  --select                  For URLs that point to files, opens the directory and selects 
                            the file, instead of opening the actual file

Arguments:  
  URL                       Location to open
```